# How do I run a threadpool with parameters, and get to put in a cancellation token as well?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a bit of WPF code for the moment. I am having a problem that I can't find an answer online, so I thought I would ask the StackOverflow community!

I have a button click event occuring, let's call this:

```
  private void CollectData(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(RunLoops, new object[] { 0, 10, 20, 30, 40});
    }
```

Which works very well and takes this massive task (RunLoops) and puts it on a non-UI thread. However, as I am passing a object with my parameters, I cannot add a CancellationTokenSource to this thread.

```
 CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();

    private async void CollectData(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var token = source.Token;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(RunLoops, new object[] { 0,10,20,30,40 }, token);
    }
```

This gives me an error: no overload method takes 3 arguments. Is there any way around this? As of now, I am trying to include a stop button in my GUI which would just call cts.Cancel(), which is very convenient for the running of this code. Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: How about Task.Run? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Action_System_Threading_CancellationToken_

Comment: hmmm I might have to do it like that, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` API, you could add the `CancellationTokenSource` to the state, for example using a `Tuple`:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(RunLoops, 
    Tuple.Create(new object[] { 0, 10, 20, 30, 40 }, token));
...

private void RunLoops(object state)
{
    Tuple<object[], CancellationToken> param = (Tuple<object[], CancellationToken>)state;

    object[] array = param.Item1;
    CancellationToken token = param.Item2;
    ...
}
```

Note that the recommended way to use the thread pool to queue work items is to use the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) since .NET Framework 4.0:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(RunLoops, new object[] { 0, 10, 20, 30, 40 }, token);
```

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation. I think I was biased towards threadpool because that's what my colleagues are using, but I've actually switched to Task.Run and it is so much more flexible than threadpool, and takes the parameters as parameters ands not as an object you've got to demistify inside your fx. Thanl you once again for the help!

Comment: @woofwoof: You're welcome. Please remember to accept the answer to close the question. Thanks in advance.